# Dialogue box buttons don't work in Eclipse on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, gnome, eclipse, gtk

I am having trouble with Eclipse 3.5 on Ubuntu. After I upgraded from Ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10 I have discovered that buttons with dialogue boxes no longer work correctly - nothing happens when clicking one.

This occurred only after the upgrade, so I'm guessing it's something to with the new Gnome or GTK libraries.

A bit more detail of my environment:

- Ubuntu desktop 9.10 64bit
- Compiz (nvidia) on dual screen
- Java from package `openjdk-6-jdk`
- Eclipse 3.5 from eclipse.org binary

I am able to use the keyboard to select/activate buttons as a temporary workaround, but I would appreciate a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's apparently a known bug in Eclipse + Compiz that can be fixed by setting GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true before running eclipse.

http://mou.me.uk/2009/10/31/fixing-eclipse-in-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/

Comment: I have this bug and I'm *not* running compiz (running metcity). This does fix it however. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

Try to deactivate Compiz and see if it helps, maybe it has problems with the dialog from Eclipse on your computer, and it makes them appear, but doesn't take mouse events after. (like an unfinished animation or something).

**Edit:** Ok, so Compiz is the problem, according to your comment.
To make a smaller workaround, at first, maybe simply deactivate Compiz effects on small windows like dialogs, I remember there was such option. Maybe you can keep it for most windows, this way.

Other than that, besides trying to change parameters in Compiz, I don't have a better solution, for now.

Comment: Disabling Compiz does fix this - thank you. It's only a workaround, so I'm going to look for a better solution (I miss the scale plugin too much!).

Comment: It's not compiz. I had the same problem and I'm not running compiz

Comment: @Draemon - for Chris Harcourt, it was linked to Compiz. consider asking a new question, for yourself, referring eventually to this one, explaining your problem, and giving details about your configuration. This place is not a forum, it is a place for questions to be asked and answered. Check the FAQ (http://superuser.com/faq) for more information about this site.

Comment: @Gnoupi: Just because disabling compiz fixed doesn't mean it's a compiz problem. My problem had *exactly* the same symptoms, and was fixed by *exactly* the same solution (GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true). The root cause of the problem really isn't compiz, you've just found a second workaround that doesn't work as well as the GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true one. When exactly did I say this was a forum?

Comment: @Draemon - I was telling that for you, that's all. Because the way this site works, is as a Q&A site. A solution was accepted to this question, by someone else, which means this question will never pop back to the front page anymore, and you will not have a chance to get an answer. I found your comment only because it was under my answer. If you are interested in getting an answer, ask your own question, with your details, explaining that it's like this one, but the accepted solution doesn't solve the problem. This way you will be able to give feedback, and maybe find a solution, that's all.

Comment: @Draemon - That's why I said that it was not like a forum, because it's only for individual questions. If you want to push it further, you can't do it by just "joining" the comments, you have to ask your own question. Of course, nobody forces you, it is only a proposition, if you wanted to push the problem further, to find a solution.

Comment: @Gnoupi I don't think you're paying attention. The accepted solution *does* solve my problem, and for that reason the analysis is just plain wrong. You might not care, but others might. My problem is solved. I am not treating this like a forum - just adding a comment pointing out flaws in the answers given to solve a certain problem. FYI I'm fully aware of how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue. I don't have a fix, but you can click on a button and hit space/enter to activate it. You can use the keyboard for dialog boxes.