# Why doesn't my environment variable get set?

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, environment-variables

I have to set an environment variable called `GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS` to fix [the problem with Eclipse buttons in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/67643/dialogue-box-buttons-dont-work-in-eclipse-on-ubuntu-9-10). To set the environment variable, I added the following line to `~/.pam_environment`.

> GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS DEFAULT=true

Surprisingly, the environment variable doesn't get set when I `echo $GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS` in a terminal. However, all other environment variables that I've listed in `~/.pam_environment` are set properly. Besides, when I switch to a tty, e.g. `Alt+Ctrl+F1`, the environment variable gets set correctly. What's wrong with setting this environment variable in `~/.pam_environment`?

Comment: did you restart your X session?

Comment: Yes, I restarted my X session by logging out and in, and even restarting the machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like it's just a bug that my environment variable is not being set.

Comment: It's not a bug. That's not a valid syntax for ~/.pam_environment. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/pam_env.conf.5.html

Comment: @Gili My example matches the syntax `VARIABLE [DEFAULT=[value]] [OVERRIDE=[value]]` at the link you posted. Note that I'm using `${}` rather than `@{}` to refer to `HOME` and `PATH` because they are environment variables.

Comment: Not likely a bug, something else probably overrides it later, like your X profile as it
 works with just a shell.

The `VARIABLE [DEFAULT=[value]] [OVERRIDE=[value]]` syntax is valid for `~/.pam_environment`.
`${HOME}` and `${PATH}` are empty at this point because it runs so early, but you can set them here.
`@{HOME}` refers to the home as specified in `/etc/passwd`.

Note that environment variables (and `@{HOME}` and `@{SHELL}`) are **not** expanded in the `name=value` syntax, you have to use `name DEFAULT=value [OVERRIDE=val2]` for that.

Comment: False. The VARIABLE [DEFAULT=[value]] [OVERRIDE=[value]] syntax is the $HOME/.pam_environment syntax (see man 7 pam_env user_envfile). Also, even the /etc/environment syntax does not work in $HOME/.pam_environment. There is a bug and telling otherwise is confusing people and lead to it never getting fixed. And it is plain wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As you have identified, your environment variables should be set in `~/.pam_environment` as recommended on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables.  Easier said than done ;)

It is possible that you ran into the same configuration gap that existed for me.  See the workaround for encrypted home below.

#### My `~/.pam_environment`:

```
PATH            DEFAULT=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:${HOME}/bin
IDEA_JDK        DEFAULT=${HOME}/Applications/jdk
```

Why the ugly static path? `${PATH}` would not work for me. I bricked my login several times trying to work around it so I am sticking with the ugly static copy of the defaults :)

#### Workaround for encrypted home folders

In Ubuntu releases up to and including [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) Beta 2, if you are using an encrypted home directory you will need to modify `/etc/pam.d/common-session` to get it to load `~/.pam_environment`. This solution apparently works for earlier releases, but I have not tested it.

#### [Guenther Montag (g-montag) wrote on 2010-08-19:](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/584249/comments/1)

> This seems to be an issue with encrypted home directories. I added
>
> session required pam_env.so
>
> at the end of /etc/pam.d/common-session and now ~/.pam_environment gets read. On another system without encrypted home directories (also 10.04) the work around is not needed. Perhaps in my case the system tries to read ~/.pam_environment before it is decrypted.

Comment: My home folder is not encrypted.

Comment: Seems $HOME/.pam_environment was broken around ubuntu 13. That might be why Alain the settings worked for Alain.

Answer (score 3):

Stick to the simple "key=value" syntax in the ~/.pam_environment file. No DEFAULT, OVERRIDE, ${HOME}, no nothing. Just key=value. The man page you linked to is for pam_env.conf, only. See "man 8 pam_env" which does not promise anything else "This module can also parse a file with simple KEY=VAL pairs on separate lines.".

By the way putting something like PATH=${PATH}:more/paths in ./pam_environment is a great way to break almost any attempt to login, since the PATH gets set to ${PATH}:more/paths *literally* (not much to be found there). To rescue, "/bin/mv .pam_environment out_of_the_way" and re-login.

Comment: But system software (e.g. [Ubuntu MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE) and [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)), e.g. [20.04 LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases)) changes the content of file `~/.pam_environment` with lines such as `LC_TIME DEFAULT=en_DK.UTF-8`, suggesting it is valid. Are they in error?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It is conceivable that my answer from 2013 does not accurately describe the situation in 2020.

Comment: It was always wrong. $HOME/.pam_environment is not like /etc/environment. man 7 pam_env.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in between GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS and DEFAULT=true . This differs from the example you linked.

Try:

GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true

Comment: `pam_env` doesn't use shell syntax. http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_env.conf

Comment: @kmarsh My example matches the syntax `VARIABLE [DEFAULT=[value]] [OVERRIDE=[value]]` at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/pam_env.conf.5.html. This explains the space before `DEFAULT`.

Comment: @reprogrammer That manpage only applies to /etc/security/pam_env.conf.  ~/.pam_environment and /etc/environment use a simpler syntax.

Comment: No $HOME/.pam_environment is not /etc/environment syntax. see man 7 pam_env . user_envfile is same syntax as /etc/security/pam_env.conf .

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because when you start a terminal you are not launching a login session. It's a terminal session, and it works with different rules.

I never really got the difference and the need to differentiate, but in any case I suggest you to use ~/.bash_profile and/or ~/.bashrc to achieve the same result, unless you have been suggested to use pam for specific reasons.

Comment: It's recommended to use .pam_environment not shell scripts. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 0):

In Debian bullseye (probably way back to around 2013) and ubuntu back to at least 14.04 (tested in a docker container), ~/.pam_environment is not read per user_endir defaults to off for pam_env (see `man 7 pam_env`).
If you want to reenable it:

```
echo 'session optional pam_env.so user_readenv=1' >> /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

that is, set for an interactive session (CLI or graphical logins, like su) the pam_env with user_reader at 1.

I believe it was disabled upstream due to:

> https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2010-4708 "
> The pam_env module in Linux-PAM (aka pam) 1.1.2 and earlier reads the .pam_environment file in a user's home directory, which might allow local users to run programs with an unintended environment by executing a program that relies on the pam_env PAM check.
> "

Thought the above description is not clear to me. If it means that ~/.pam_environment allows to change the program environment without the user knowing then any option n the home folder is alike (ie ~/.profile, ~/.zprofile). Mind ~/.profile is told to be read by graphical login managers ... so why remove ~/.pam_environment and keep ~/.profile?

A proper way would be to have the capability to set environment variables per user in /etc/security/pam_env.conf. Not yet requested upstream though. Or any option editable only with admin rights.